# Swift: Can't set the background of custom UITableViewCell to .clear

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have created the following UITableViewCell

```
class SeasonTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

static let identifier = "SeasonTableViewCell"

private var seasonLabel: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.numberOfLines = 1
    label.textAlignment = .center
    return label
}()

override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    contentView.backgroundColor = .clear
    [seasonLabel].forEach { contentView.addSubview($0) }
    setConstraints()
}

...

}
```

However, the cells render with the default background. If however I try to use any other color:

```
contentView.backgroundColor = .red
```

This does work. It's just with .clear that it doesn't work.

I have also tried the following when dequeueing the cell:

```
cell.backgroundView?.backgroundColor = .clear
```

But this doesn't work either.

How can I make the cell have a transparent background?

Comment: In the initializer, `backgroundColor = UIColor.clear` should be enough. You don't need to paint the content view. Make sure also the table view itself has the appropriate color, and the view that the table is in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the comment says  `self.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear` is enough in `init` at `TableviewCell` to give background color to cell.

If your main color is in `Viewcontroller's view` make

```
tableview.backgroundColor = .clear // in view
and
self.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear // in cell init class
```

If your main color is in tableview's background, just make

```
 self.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear // in cell init class
```

I don't see inside the `setConstraints` method but I think the label covers the whole cell and if the label has a background color this may result in not getting the result you want.Don't ignore it either